# IDA search results not showing up in a separate window

Tags: ida, static-analysis

I'm just learning to use IDA and according to the book, when using `Search` function (`Search>text...`, for example) I should see a window with the found results, like this:
[image: screenshot from the book]

However, when the search is over, if something is found, I only see in the bottom Search completed text and if I scroll the IDA View-A window, I can see that the text is highlighted. Text string `gethostbyname` was searched here:
[image: screenshot of IDA in use]
I cannot see all the instances at the same time as expected.

The version I use is IDA 5.0, free version; it's the same version that the book was based on. How can I get the results to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need to check the checkmark find all occurances
else ida stops when it finds the first occurance and the window doesnt open up

[image]